# What causes HPLC peaks to look like gauss curves?

Tags: physical-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, elemental-analysis

I was wondering how the form and curvature of HPLC peaks come to be. As I understand it, the mobile phase which contains the analyte, runs through the column. Many times, the distribution equilibrium is established inside the column, so the analyte is held back in the column. Finally, in the detector, peaks like a gaussian curve like this are recorded:

[image]

What causes the form of a peak to look like a gauss curve? I suppose more analyte is detected at the halfway point of the peak, but why?

Comment: This must be described in many textbooks and internet sites focusing on chromatography, as it is foundation of all chromatographic techniques. // Simulate multistage extraction with shifting mobile phase steps. It turns out it follows binomial distribution, converging to Gauss curve.

Comment: You are asking 2 different questions. "What causes the form of a peak to look like a gauss curve?" : as Poutnik said, this is well explained by many sources, but in essence it's down to diffusion. Imagine the initial sample as a very short cylinder on top of the column, which would result in a narrow ~rectangle when detected. As the solvent carries this cylinder through the column, the molecules in it also diffuse in all directions, resulting in a random distribution, which translates to a ~gaussian peak.

Comment: "I suppose more analyte is detected at the halfway point of the peak, but why?". That's an approximation, but is justified for the same reasons as above. If the shape resulting from the above mentioned processes is ~gaussian, the mode and mean ~coincide. The mean occurs at 'half time', and so ~does the highest concentration.

Comment: Even in this picture it's quite visible it's not Gauss curve.

Comment: @Mithoron "Why to spoil a good story by the truth?" :-} We know the world is not ideal and there are always some effects not  involved in education models. // There are 3 factors, Diffusion, prevalent at slow linear mobile phase speed, analyte transfer delay, prevalent at high speeds, and speed independent factor due dispersion of mobile phase passed distance. // Peak distorsion is often caused by nonlinear distribution between phases.

Comment: P.S.: E.g. for typical reversed phase HPLC column with silicagel substituted by C18 chains, there may be residual polar OH groups, capturing analyte more strongly then nonpolar C18 chains. This leads to trailing peaks. Another trailing reason may be wrong or badly maintained sample injection, with trailing sample insertion. This is more common in GC.

Comment: I'm with Poutnik on this. One can analyse/model physical processes at any required degree of accuracy, and as pointed out, there are textbooks and sources that explain (and account for) the chromatographic process in very intricate detail. Perhaps the tone of the question seemed to indicate that the OP was after some semi-qualitative explanation for the _approximate_ shape of the HPLC peak, and diffusion processes are the answer to _that_ question. If the OP had asked for the _exact_ mathematical treatment of the shape of HPLC peaks, one would be right to point out that it's not a gaussian.